# Is there an English name for 过家家?

Tags: translation

过家家 is a children's game, in which children mimic adults to run households. Activities includes preparing and serving make-believe dinners, looking after babies and pretending to be husbands and wives, doctors and cashiers. There is no rule.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be 'playing house'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be translated as  play house